# For loops and advice

Tags: loops, batch-file, variables

I know this has been asked a million times but I just dont get it.

I have the following line in a text file:

```
Pinging ERL-DFEIST03.XXXXXX.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
```

It is the first line.

I need the 2nd part. The `ERL-DFEIST03.XXXXXX.com`

I found a code online that will get me the first word, but no matter what I do, I cannot get the 2nd or understand why I cannot.

Can someone please show me how to fix the code?

```
@echo off

for /f %%b in (c:\Temp\IP_temp.txt) do (
  echo %%b
  pause
  exit /b
)
```

Comment: You could parse the information directly from the `ping` command, as opposed to sending all of the output to a file, then reading and parsing the file. Are you sure you just want assistance with parsing the first line of content from a file?

Comment: BY default the line of text is broken up into `TOKENS` by the default delimiters of `TAB` and `SPACE`.  You can control which token and delimiters you want o use by using the `TOKENS` and `DELIMS` options.  So in your case you want `TOKEN` number 2 with a space as a delimiter.  Since the default delimiter is a space you don't need to do anything with the `DELIMS` option.

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2" %%I in ('ping …') do echo/%%I& goto :NEXT`, then `:NEXT` i the next line…

Comment: I've just realized, the not only is the result you're looking for, in normal circumstances, the second line output from a `ping` command, not the first, but it would also be the result of pinging the string you're looking for. For example, if you `ping stackoverflow.com`, the result would look like this for you: `Pinging stackoverflow.com [151.101.193.69] with 32 bytes of data:`. If you didn't already know the domain name, e.g. `ping 151.101.193.69`, then the result would look like this for you: `Pinging 151.101.193.69 with 32 bytes of data:`. So why do you need to capture a string you input?

Answer (score 2):

Just to confuse you further, you could do what your question currently requires/asks, without a `for` loop at all!

```sh
@Set /P "WhoIs=" 0< "C:\Temp\IP_temp.txt"
@Set "WhoIs=%WhoIs: [="&:"%"
@Echo(%WhoIs:* =%
@Pause
```

Comment: Try `set "n=2" & set "item=%WhoIs: =" & set /A "n-=1" & (if !n! equ 0 set "out=!item!") & set "item=%"` Put the number of the space-separated desired item in `n`. The result is in `out`

Comment: I don't see any benefit in that @Aacini, _(other than introducing a greater degree of confusion)_. I wasn't intending to split on space characters as delimiters, otherwise I'd have just posted a `for` loop and I wasn't willing to do that, because it was solveable by reading the usage information for the specific command they were using. This idea was, _regardless of whether spaces could exist within the domain string_, to isolate everything from the initial space up until the space prior to the first square bracket. Mine fails if the domain string has `space[`; yours if it has a `space`.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps in this case my method don't give any advantage, but it allows to separate items based on _substrings_, not just characters like `for /F`

Comment: TBF @Aacini, I wouldn't guarantee that the output from `ping.exe` will never contain multiple adjacent spaces either!

Comment: I appreciate the help. 1 thing I guess I should have said is I need to ping a pc on my network and get the name. I know there are ways to do it, this is just what I came up with.....

Comment: @doheth, did you see [my comment under your question proper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590007/for-loops-and-advice/69590326?noredirect=1#comment123022209_69590007). I'm not sure that the FQDN is not output in that line, unless you provide it yourself in that `ping` command. Could you please show us what you are entering in the `ping` command? and what is being returned? Perhaps you should not be using `ping` in the first instance.

Comment: @Compo I may have been wrong this entire time. When I ping -a I just get a normal ping. I was hoping to get the pc name. But it looks like I cannot this way. I will have to find another way. Does anyone have any ideas??

Comment: @doheth, this site does not pefrom your research for you, or tell you how to go about performing your tasks. Please use the search facility at the top of the page, and/or your chosen web search provider or published materials to find and select a method of determining a FQDN from an IP Address, within your particular environment and set of circumstances. Once you've chosen a suitable command or set of commands, which provide the results you require, feel free to open another question, complete with that code and the exact output it returns, and somebody will try to assist you, should it fail.

Comment: @Compo Since I made a mistake in what I was asking for, can you tell me how to close the question? And I would like to thank everyone for the input

Comment: @doheth, please create a text file, with the first line `Pinging ERL-DFEIST03.XXXXXX.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:`, name the file `IP_temp.txt`, and place it inside a directory in ```C:\``` named `Temp`. Then run my code, and see what is output. If the code returns `ERL-DFEIST03.XXXXXX.com`, then accept my solution, as it answers the question you asked. Please do not be rude, and just ignore the time and effort others have given in order to assist you, by deleting a question which has been answered by somebody already, especially if it does exactly what was requested. Thank you.